# AngularJS: serverside logging of clientside errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs, exception, logging, error-handling

I've rewritten a web application using angular. But now i have the problem that it's not as easy as `window.onerror = function(...) { ... }` to send clientside errors to the server. But this is really helpful to detect errors.

I added a custom exception handler to angular using the following code

```
    $provide.decorator("$exceptionHandler", function($delegate) {
    return function(exception, cause) {
        $delegate(exception, cause);
        log2server(exception + " (" + cause + ")");
    };
});
```

But this wont allow me to get the location where the exception came from. Any hints/experience how to tackle this? I would also love a solution which is able to work with http://stacktracejs.com/

Comment: For reference, we can now have the stack trace information from the exception object. exception.message and exception.stack. More information can be found here: http://www.ozkary.com/2016/04/angularjs-log-client-errors-to-server.html

Comment: see here for a working stacktrace-to-home solution ➝ http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2542-logging-client-side-errors-with-angularjs-and-stacktrace-js.htm

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm currently using [TraceKit](https://github.com/occ/TraceKit) which seems to work quite well.

Simply add this to your angular startup-code

```
$provide.decorator("$exceptionHandler", function($delegate) {
    return function(exception, cause) {
        TraceKit.report(exception);
        $delegate(exception, cause);
    };
});
```

+this somewhere

```
TraceKit.report.subscribe(function(errorReport) {
    var msg = 'msg: ' + errorReport.message + '\n\n';
    msg +="::::STACKTRACE::::\n"
    for(var i = 0; i < errorReport.stack.length; i++) {
        msg += "stack[" + i + "] " + errorReport.stack[i].url + ":" + errorReport.stack[i].line + "\n";
    }
    // log to server
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

We could use [stacktrace.js by Eric Wendelin](http://www.stacktracejs.com/)

1. `AngularJS` has good error handling.
2. `stacktrace.js` tries to solve important problem of getting right error information across all the browsers.

So We could create an angular wrapper around stacktrace.js which gives a comprehensive error handling.

Following are the 2 blog posts that explains very nicely, how to log client side JS error to server side using `AngularJS` and `stacktrace.js`.

1. http://engineering.talis.com/articles/client-side-error-logging/
2. http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2542-logging-client-side-errors-with-angularjs-and-stacktrace-js.htm

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: Im django-based applications developer.

I can propose you using [raven](http://raven.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)-based solution. It is logging agregation service with many bindings(also [javascript](https://github.com/getsentry/raven-js)), and great monitoring app [sentry](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry) based on django.